# Scrape list elements under tags for multiple websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of websites, for example:

```
['http://www.crowncastle.com','http://www.cadmusgroup.com','https://www.ni.com/en-in.html','https://ricardo.com/','https://volkert.com/','http://www.lynx.com','https://www.bv.com/']
```

How to scrape the contents from the "menu" or "navigation bar" of these websites such that the hierarchy of the contents is maintained;

With the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'http://www.crowncastle.com'
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(html_text, 'html.parser')
d = {}

for e in soup.select('nav > ul > li'):
    s = list(e.stripped_strings)
    d.update({s[0]: s[1:]})

display(d)
```

I get the following Output:

```
{'Municipalities': [],
 'Property Owners': [],
 'Investors': [],
 'CCIsites': [],
 'Careers': [],
 'About us': [],
 'Infrastructure Solutions': ['View all solutions',
  'See our network map',
  'Wireless solutions',
  'Towers',
  'Small cells',
  'Fiber solutions',
  'Dark Fiber',
  'Ethernet',
  'Wavelength',
  'Managed SD-WAN',
  'Internet Access',
  'Private Networks',
  'Colocation',
  'Added fiber solutions',
  'Cloud Connect',
  'Optical Encryption',
  'DDoS Defense',
  'Managed Security',
  'Bandwidth on Demand',
  'Fixed Wireless',
  'Ultra-Low Latency',
  'Video Transport',
  'Close submenu'],
 'Industry expertise': ['Overview',
  'End-to-end service delivery',
  'Case studies',
  'Accelerating network connections',
  'Financial Services',
  'Professional Services',
  'Technology Companies',
  'Gaming',
  'Media & Entertainment',
  'Transforming Public Infrastructure',
  'Federal Government',
  'State and Local Government',
  'Education',
  'Healthcare',
  'Utilities',
  'Public Safety',
  'Scaling Networks Nationwide',
  'Wireless Carriers',
  'Broadcast',
  'WISPs and Other Telecoms',
  'Cable',
  'Wholesale',
  'Enhancing Visitor Experiences',
  'Commercial Real Estate',
  'Venues',
  'Hospitality',
  'Retail',
  'Building Industrial Networks',
  'Manufacturing',
  'Oil and Gas',
  'Internet of Things',
  'Transportation',
  'Close submenu'],
 'YOUR COMMUNITY': [],
 'News': [],
 'Network Operations Center': [],
 'Channel Partners': [],
 'Fiber Referral Rewards': [],
 'Connected by Good': [],
 'ESG Overview': [],
 'Suppliers': [],
 'Media Center': [],
 'Resources': [],
 'Our History': [],
 'Contact Us': []}
```

However, All the contents under **Infrastructure Solutions** are present in a *single list*.

What's required is ...

e.g., for ... https://www.crowncastle.com/
[image: https://www.crowncastle.com/]

Similarly, for
https://ricardo.com/

[image: https://ricardo.com/]

What I would like to have is to have a Dictionary under the Key corresponding to a keyword in the main navigation bar, so that it is possible to track hierarchy of keywords.

```
{'Infrastructure Solutions': {'Wireless Solutions': ['Towers', 'Small Cells'],'Fiber Solutions':['Dark Fiber','Ethernet',...]}}
```

As I have to work with a lot of websites it won't be possible to get the class for each websites' navigation bar. So what I am looking for is a more **generalized approach** which can preserve "ul" under "ul" tags. Hence, I can only work with tags to make a more generalized approach for extracting the contents of menu bar.

Comment: why is this tagged with selenium?

Comment: @Hannonqaoud I have tried scraping with beautiful soup but if it is possible to solve the problem with selenium then why not?

Comment: its very unlikely that one script can scrape multiple websites and get the exact result you expected, one approach you can follow, is to collect all the lists on the page and manually dismiss ones you dont need which is already similar to what you've done, Also selenium is not a better solution than a normal request.